# Angular2/Nativescript: Strange "Unexpected tag" error when nesting StackLayouts

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with an Angular2 Nativescript app which worked perfectly fine before but after moving a input field to another part of my view I get the below errors saying Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout"...  Any idea what could be causing this?  Is there a limit to the number of stack layouts that can be nested inside each other?  The input field I moved to a different part of the view is the qty input field...

The error I get:

```
JS: ns-renderer: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR
JS: ns-renderer: Template parse errors:
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" ("Field class="input input-border" hint="Enter Quantity" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="qty">
JS:                             [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>
JS:                             <Button class="btn btn-primary pull-right font-awesome" text="&#xf058;  Capture" ("): StockTakeComponent@37:4
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" ("me" text="&#xf058;  Capture" (tap)="capture()" [isEnabled]="qty !== '' && qty != null"></Button>
JS:                     [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>
JS:             </StackLayout>
JS:
JS: "): StockTakeComponent@39:3
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" (";  Capture" (tap)="capture()" [isEnabled]="qty !== '' && qty != null"></Button>
JS:                     </StackLayout>
JS:             [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>
JS:
JS:             <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of stockTakeDetailList" *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.l"): StockTakeComponent@40:2
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" ("nt-awesome" text="&#xf1f8; remove" (tap)="removeCaptureItem(item.IDKey)"></Button>
JS:     </StackLayout>
JS:     [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>
JS: </StackLayout>"): StockTakeComponent@47:1
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" ("
JS:     </StackLayout>
JS:     </StackLayout>
JS: [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>"): StockTakeComponent@48:0
JS:
JS: Error: Template parse errors:
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" ("Field class="input input-border" hint="Enter Quantity" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="qty">
JS:                             [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>
JS:                             <Button class="btn btn-primary pull-right font-awesome" text="&#xf058;  Capture" ("): StockTakeComponent@37:4
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" ("me" text="&#xf058;  Capture" (tap)="capture()" [isEnabled]="qty !== '' && qty != null"></Button>
JS:                     [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>
JS:             </StackLayout>
JS:
JS: "): StockTakeComponent@39:3
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" (";  Capture" (tap)="capture()" [isEnabled]="qty !== '' && qty != null"></Button>
JS:                     </StackLayout>
JS:             [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>
JS:
JS:             <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of stockTakeDetailList" *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.l"): StockTakeComponent@40:2
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" ("nt-awesome" text="&#xf1f8; remove" (tap)="removeCaptureItem(item.IDKey)"></Button>
JS:     </StackLayout>
JS:     [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>
JS: </StackLayout>"): StockTakeComponent@47:1
JS: Unexpected closing tag "StackLayout" ("
JS:     </StackLayout>
JS:     </StackLayout>
JS: [ERROR ->]</StackLayout>"): StockTakeComponent@48:0
JS:     at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13337:21)
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13324:53
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:190:28)
JS:     at Zone.run (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:83:43)
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:449:57
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:223:37)
JS:     at Zone.runTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:123:47)
JS:     at drainMicroTaskQueue (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:355:35)
1:54:21 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

And here is my Component HTML code:

```
<StackLayout class="page">
    <ActionBar title="Stock Take" android.icon="res://icon" android.iconVisibility="always"></ActionBar>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="!stockTaking">
        <Label class="h1 title m-x-auto" text="Begin Stock Take?"></Label>
        <StackLayout class="form">  
            <StackLayout class="input-field">               
                <ListView [items]="activeStockTakes" class="list-group" (itemTap)="selectActiveStockTake($event.target.value)">
                <template let-activeStockTake="item">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label class="list-group-item" [text]="activeStockTake.UserCode + ' - ' + activeStockTake.Comment"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
                </template>
                </ListView>
                <TextField class="input input-border tf" hint="Enter Sheet Number" placeholderColor="white" [(ngModel)]="sheetNo"></TextField>
                <TextField class="input input-border" hint="Enter Bin Number" [(ngModel)]="binNo"></TextField>          
            </StackLayout>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary font-awesome" text="&#xf04b; Start Stock Take" (tap)="startStockTake()" [isEnabled]="sheetNo !== '' && sheetNo != null && binNo !== '' && binNo != null"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="stockTaking">
        <StackLayout class="form">
            <Button id="endStockTakeBtn" class="btn pull-right font-awesome" text="&#xf00d; End Stock Take" (tap)="endStockTake()"></Button>
            <StackLayout class="input-field">       
                <TextField class="input input-border" hint="Enter Barcode" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="barcode"></TextField>     
            </StackLayout>

            <Button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" text="Scan" (tap)="scan()" [isEnabled]="barcode !== '' && barcode != null"></Button>

        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *ngIf="product" class="m-x-auto">
            <Label class="label text-primary" [text]="'Description:  ' + product.Description"></Label>
            <Label class="label text-primary" [text]="'POS Description: ' + product.POSDescription"></Label>
            <Label class="label text-primary" [text]="'POS price:  R' + product.POSPrice"></Label>
            <Label class="label text-primary" [text]="'Stock On Hand:  ' + product.StockOnHand"></Label>
            <StackLayout class="form">
                <StackLayout class="input-field">
                    <TextField class="input input-border" hint="Enter Quantity" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="qty">
                </StackLayout>              
                <Button class="btn btn-primary pull-right font-awesome" text="&#xf058;  Capture" (tap)="capture()" [isEnabled]="qty !== '' && qty != null"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of stockTakeDetailList" *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0">
            <Label [text]="'Name: ' + item.ProductDetail_Name" class="text-primary"></Label>            
            <Label text="'Qty: ' + item.Qty" class="text-primary"></Label>          
            <Button class="btn btn-primary pull-left font-awesome" text="&#xf1f8; remove" (tap)="removeCaptureItem(item.IDKey)"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like you have one or two extra `</StackLayout> tags

Comment: @mast3rd3mon  Where do you see those extra stackLayout tags?

Comment: Everytime it says `[ERROR ->]</StackLayout>`. Either that or you're missing a close tag for something else

Comment: You need to include the screen here for us to be able to see why.   Based on the error mast3rd3mon is probably correct that you are either missing a closing tag inside the new StackLayout tag or you have an extra closing StackLayout.

Comment: Can you share the html of that Component?

Comment: @Vladimir Amiorkov The html is below the error.

Comment: @Nathanael The screen/view code is below the error...

Comment: @user2094257 I see you have added the ActionBar (Stock Take) to the first StackLayout, this should be at the root level of the HTML, move it outside of that StackLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your issue:

```
 <StackLayout class="input-field">
       <TextField class="input input-border" hint="Enter Quantity" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="qty">
 </StackLayout>
```

You forgot the closing `</TextField>`  The next closing tag is the `/StackLayout` which it is throwing the error on because it doesn't match the `TextField` before it.

Comment: Thanks @Nathanael

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error inn this following line cause the error when using font awesome

```
nt-awesome" text="&#xf1f8;
```

and try resolve it using : [fonticon-nativescript angular](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-ngx-fonticon)